# If something gets out of the panel in the top side then make it go to (0, 0) position, if in the botton side then (0, Panel Height Size)

Tags: vb.net, slider, scrollbar, custom-controls

So basically I've been trying to program a custom ScrollBar for my WinForm written in VB.NET and I don't seem to make it have a limit of the movement.

Code without limit tries:

```
Public Class GoldSrcScrollBar
    Dim drag As Boolean
    Dim mousey As Integer

    Private Sub GoldSrcScrollBtn1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GoldSrcScrollBtn1.MouseDown
        drag = True
        mousey = Cursor.Position.Y - GoldSrcScrollBtn1.Top
    End Sub

    Private Sub GoldSrcScrollBtn1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GoldSrcScrollBtn1.MouseUp
        drag = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub GoldSrcScrollBtn1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles GoldSrcScrollBtn1.MouseMove
        If drag Then
            GoldSrcScrollBtn1.Top = Cursor.Position.Y - mousey
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have no idea how to make it have a limit

[image]

```
Slider = GoldSrcScrollBtn1
ScrollBar Background = GoldSrcScrollBarBg1
```

Without limit it works like this:

[image]

As you can see, it gets out of the Panel (`GoldSrcScrollBarBg1`).
Could someone help me please? Thanks :)

Comment: The `If` conditions in the `MouseMove` event handler are wrong. Use the debugger (or write to the Output Window (`Console.WriteLine()`), in this case) to verify what values you're actually setting/comparing.

Comment: Oh sorry, ignore the "Else If" part, I knew it was wrong and I just forgot to delete it

Comment: All right, now there's the debugging/measuring part to fix. Look at the values.

Comment: Everything works fine, I just have no idea how to code something like "Collision" for it to make it not go any further than the panel (scrollbar background) size